# How to remove Cortana, Connect, Get Help etc from Start Menue

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I'm trying to find a way of removing the entries for Cotana, Connect, and Get Help from the start menu. All other programs - upon a right click - allow me to view their file location, where I can delete their shortcut.

Is there any way to remove the above-listed Windows apps from the start menu? Thanks!

Comment: No, that cause problems. Is there a way to remove the other start menu items, bar Cortana? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I am fine with removing both Connect, and Support. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to remove the above-listed Windows apps from the
>   start menu?

The package name for `Get Help` is `Microsoft.GetHelp_10.1706.1981.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

You can remove it, permanently from your system,  with the following command in an elevated command prompt.

```
DISM /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.GetHelp_10.1706.1981.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

As for the Connect application, I am going under an educated assumption, it's package is `Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy`.

You can permanently remove that package by using the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt.

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy | Remove-AppxPackage
```

I used the following commands to determine which package belonged to which application.

- `Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName`
- `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Select DisplayName | Sort DisplayName`

Comment: I personally don't recommend removing Connect, but it's your choice, it seems connected to the Settings application in some capacity.  It is also worth pointing out, you likely will have to uninstall these applications again, if you install a feature update.  Just the nature of the feature updates, and considering they must be installed eventually, just something you will have to live with.

Comment: That's incredibly kind, thank you for the help!

Comment: I am confident that you will be able to remove Windows.MiracastView since it's not a provisioned package, but Microsoft made it more difficult to remove provisioned packages, with 1607+ so I am interested if these command will work.  I see to recall one PowerShell method to remove UWP applications no longer works, resources used to write this answer, were dated Oct/Nov and both commands were used up until then.

Comment: Worth pointing out I don't actually suggest you remove these application.  They can easily be hidden.  In any event an alternative to these commands is StartIsBack++, it allows you to uninstall both applications, the same was you would uninstall any UWP application from the start menu.  I don't recommend software in answers, ever, hence the reason I am using a comment.